# Blender 2.93 face orientation stopped working. What did I do wrong?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]So far face orientation has worked well but suddenly it stopped working. I must have clicked something by accident. What did I do wrong?

Comment: can you show us some screens of your settings or something? Not exactly sure what you mean by "stopped working" , when did it stop?

Comment: Yep, there is a lot of face orientation indicators, that you can use, try to clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you MikoCG, Crantisz and moonboots. I added a screenshot. The Face Orientation icon in the Viewport Overlays window is checked.

Answer (score 1):

It's looks like it completely transparent, try to add alpha a little:

[image]

Also check here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Crantisz so much, this is exactly the solution to the issue 